# How to map specialization with covering constraints in sql server

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, refer

I have two tables, 'PublishedBook' and 'TextBook', which specialize "Items" entity. 'PublishedBook' and 'TextBook' cover 'items'.No overlapping as well. I think that to illustrate this I need to do something impossible like this;

```
create table TextBook
(

    itemNo char(5),
    semester varchar(5),
    section varchar(10),
    pYear int,
    constraint TextBookPK primary key(itemNo),
);


create table PublishedBook
(

    itemNo char(5),
    edition varchar(5),
    constraint PublishebookPK primary key(itemNo)
);

create table Item
(

    itemNo char(5) ,
    title  varchar(10),
    description varchar(100),
    constraint itemPK primary key(itemNo),
    constraint itemFK foreign key(itemNo) references PublishedBook(itemNo) 
    constraint itemFK2 foreign key(itemNo) references TextBook(itemNo)
);
```

Make the 'itemNo' of Item table refer to both primary keys of PublishedBook and TextBook.

Can anyone please explain me how can I go through this?

Comment: You are already doing it what is the problem with your approach?

Comment: mr.M.Ali, my way is not possible in sql server i illustrated what i think i should do... Im asking how i should do it correctly..

Comment: because there is no overlapping as well

Answer (score 0):

what you are doing is correct, you are just missing one comma after the second constraint on table Item:

```
create table TextBook
(

itemNo char(5),
semester varchar(5),
section varchar(10),
pYear int,
constraint TextBookPK primary key(itemNo),
);


create table PublishedBook
(

itemNo char(5),
edition varchar(5),
constraint PublishebookPK primary key(itemNo)
);

create table Item
(

itemNo char(5) ,
title  varchar(10),
description varchar(100),
constraint itemPK primary key(itemNo),
constraint itemFK foreign key(itemNo) references PublishedBook(itemNo) ,
constraint itemFK2 foreign key(itemNo) references TextBook(itemNo)
);
```

Comment: but when I insert data into items i got this error after correctly inserting to PublishedBook and TextBook; 
"
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "itemFK2". The conflict occurred in database "master", table "dbo.PublishedBook", column 'itemNo'.
The statement has been terminated."

Comment: are all three tables in master database?

Answer (score 0):

what is the result of this query that checks the constraints?:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE constraint_name
in(
SELECT UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE constraint_name in(
SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE constraint_type='FOREIGN KEY'
AND TABLE_NAME='Item')
)
```